# Application can't find OWIN Startup class after rename

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

So I renamed my MVC application from "Conclusion" to "ConclusionWeb" to avoid namespace errors. Since doing so I get the error "No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.". When I go to Properties the drop-down list to select a Startup Object is empty. I've added all the niceties I can find to my Startup class, below, but it isn't being detected. Any ideas?

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ConclusionWeb.App_Start
{
    [assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ConclusionWeb.App_Start.Startup))]
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using config file to specify your startup class? The config file will take precedence over your attribute.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Thanks very much. It wasn't in there but adding a config line in there has solved it. Still not sure  why the assembly didn't work or why it doesn't appear in the properties drop-down but this works. 

Also had to change an include setting in views/web.config.

Comment: The startup setting with drop down is for Windows Forms and console apps. It expects Main functions, not Startup.